# How to show Multiple Text view inside the single row of expandable List using Fire base

Tags: android, firebase, firebase-realtime-database, android-arrayadapter, expandablelistadapter

[**Firebase DB Structure**](https://i.stack.imgur.com/igk4Z.png)

[**What i Get from this Code- Current output**](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Ikpbr.png)

[**What i want - Single Row/Multiple Text (Sample Output)**](https://i.stack.imgur.com/2bogU.png)

Need to show Multiple Text View inside the single row/List with fire base values
Current code Output (Check Pic-2)

I have an expandablelistview, that the parent has 4 textviews

**MainActivity**

```
public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {
        private static final String TAG = "Check";
        // declare the variable needed in activity
        MyExpandableAdapter expandableadapter;
        ExpandableListView expandableListView;
        List<String> headersList;
        HashMap<String, List<String>> itemsMap;

        //Firebase storage references
        private FirebaseDatabase mFirebasedatabase;

        //Task database references:
        private DatabaseReference mTasksDatabaseReference;

        //My Implimentation
        List<String> tasks;

        @Override
        protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
            super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
            setContentView(R.layout.activity);

            //Initialize Firebase Components
            mFirebasedatabase = FirebaseDatabase.getInstance();
            //For Reading Tasks(Not Using For Now)
            mTasksDatabaseReference = mFirebasedatabase.getReference().child("restaurants/AGS Biriyani/bestsellers");




            //Now Saving Tasks(from firebase nodes:task1,task2,task3) to ArrayList and then adding data to HashMap
            itemsMap = new HashMap<String, List<String>>();
            headersList = new ArrayList<>();
            tasks = new ArrayList<>();

            //Getting data from firebase
            getDataFromFirebase();

            //get expandable listview
            expandableListView = (ExpandableListView) findViewById(R.id.expandlist);

            // get expandable list adapter
            expandableadapter = new MyExpandableAdapter(this, headersList, itemsMap);
            //set list adapter to list
            expandableListView.setAdapter(expandableadapter);

            //Refreshing Adapter
            expandableadapter.notifyDataSetChanged();

            //handling the header items click
            expandableListView.setOnChildClickListener(new ExpandableListView.OnChildClickListener() {
                @Override
                public boolean onChildClick(ExpandableListView parent, View v, int groupPosition, int childPosition, long id) {
                    Toast.makeText(MainActivity.this, headersList.get(groupPosition) + "--" + itemsMap.get(headersList.get(groupPosition)).get(childPosition), Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                    return false;
                }
            });
            //get the expand of headersList
            expandableListView.setOnGroupExpandListener(new ExpandableListView.OnGroupExpandListener() {
                @Override
                public void onGroupExpand(int groupPosition) {
                    Toast.makeText(MainActivity.this, headersList.get(groupPosition), Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                }
            });
            //get the collapse of headersList
            expandableListView.setOnGroupCollapseListener(new ExpandableListView.OnGroupCollapseListener() {
                @Override
                public void onGroupCollapse(int groupPosition) {
                    Toast.makeText(MainActivity.this, headersList.get(groupPosition), Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                }
            });

        }

        private void mFirebasedatabase(ValueEventListener valueEventListener) {
        }

        //Reading Data From firebase
        void getDataFromFirebase(){
            //Firebase Read Listener
            mTasksDatabaseReference.addChildEventListener(new ChildEventListener() {
                @Override
                public void onChildAdded(DataSnapshot dataSnapshot, String s) {
                    //Running Foreach loop
                    for(DataSnapshot d : dataSnapshot.getChildren()) {
                        //Getting Value from 1 to 10 in ArrayList(tasks)
                        tasks.add(d.getValue().toString());

                    }

                    //Putting key & tasks(ArrayList) in HashMap
                    itemsMap.put(dataSnapshot.getKey(),tasks);

                    headersList.add(dataSnapshot.getKey());

                    tasks=new ArrayList<>();

                    Log.d(TAG, "onChildAdded: dataSnapshot.getChildren: "+dataSnapshot.getChildren());
                    Log.d(TAG, "onChildAdded: KEY"+dataSnapshot.getKey()+" value "+dataSnapshot.getValue().toString());

                }

                @Override
                public void onChildChanged(DataSnapshot dataSnapshot, String s) {
                    Log.d(TAG, "onChildChanged: "+dataSnapshot.getValue().toString());
                }

                @Override
                public void onChildRemoved(DataSnapshot dataSnapshot) {
                    //task.remove("" + dataSnapshot.getValue());
                }

                @Override
                public void onChildMoved(DataSnapshot dataSnapshot, String s) {

                }

                @Override
                public void onCancelled(DatabaseError databaseError) {

                }
            });

            // mTasksDatabaseReference.addChildEventListener(mChildEventListener);
        }

    }
```

**MyExpandableAdapter**

```
 [public class MyExpandableAdapter extends BaseExpandableListAdapter{
        private Context con;
        private List<String> headers;
        private HashMap<String,List<String>> headeritems;


public MyExpandableAdapter(Context context, List<String> listheaders, HashMap<String,List<String>> headerchilds)
            {
                this.con=context;
                this.headers=listheaders;
                this.headeritems=headerchilds;
            }
            // get child of header
            @Override
            public Object getChild(int groupPosition, int childPosition) {
                return this.headeritems.get(this.headers.get(groupPosition)).get(childPosition);
            }
            @Override
            public long getChildId(int groupPosition, int childPosition) {
                return childPosition;
            }
            // return the view of child
            @Override
            public View getChildView(int groupPosition, int childPosition, boolean isLastChild, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {
                final String childname=(String)getChild(groupPosition,childPosition);
                if(convertView==null)
                {
                    LayoutInflater inflater=(LayoutInflater)LayoutInflater.from(con);
                    convertView=inflater.inflate(R.layout.headers_items,null);
                }
                TextView listchild=(TextView)convertView.findViewById(R.id.headeritem);
                listchild.setText(childname);
                return convertView;
            }
            // returns children count of header
            @Override
            public int getChildrenCount(int groupPosition) {
                return this.headeritems.get(headers.get(groupPosition)).size();
            }
            @Override
            public Object getGroup(int groupPosition) {
                return this.headers.get(groupPosition);
            }
            @Override
            public int getGroupCount() {
                return this.headers.size();
            }
            @Override
            public long getGroupId(int groupPosition) {
                return groupPosition;
            }

            //returns the view of group
            @Override
            public View getGroupView(int groupPosition, boolean isExpanded, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {
                String headername=(String)getGroup(groupPosition);
                if(convertView==null)
                {
                    LayoutInflater inflater=LayoutInflater.from(con);
                    convertView=inflater.inflate(R.layout.listview_header,null);
                }
                TextView header=(TextView)convertView.findViewById(R.id.expandheader);
                header.setText(headername);
                return convertView;
            }
            @Override
            public boolean isChildSelectable(int groupPosition, int childPosition) {
                return true;
            }
            @Override
            public boolean hasStableIds() {
                return false;
            }
        }
```

Comment: Have you tried to create a custom layout for your row that contains all those elements?

Comment: Yes @AlexMamo , I can able to get Firebase Values in  tasks.add(d.getValue().toString()) in MainActiity but Don't Know how to add in MyExpandableAdapter

Comment: @AlexMamo, i want pass the data(which i get from fire base - MainActivity) into hash map(key,data) and  using array list(to store the data) against each key.